# Select rows from a text file by a matching pattern in one column

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have a file in the following format.

```
Table_name Value
Employee   0
student    50
Payroll    0
animals    20
```

I need to fetch the entire row in which the value is non-zero.

The expected output would be

```
student    50
animals    20
```

If the value is zero for all the rows, I should get a mail alert like "all values are zero".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not perl:

```
perl -ane 'print if($.!=1 && $F[1]!=0)' your_file
```

Comment: I have only Unix environment

Comment: Perl is part of the standard Unix environment.

Answer (score 2):

This can work:

```
$ awk '$2' file
Table_name Value
student    50
animals    20
```

If the 2th field is not `0` then the condition is evaluated as true - note that `{print $0}` is the default block in `awk` so it can be omitted if this is the only action you want to perform.

Regarding the mail alert, I think you'd better show some of your code to have a refer point.

Comment: Its not `can`. it should be `will`

Comment: I am not getting you. Your command would give you the below output  0 50 0 20 right? I want the whole row.

Comment: @Vignesh, the command will give the output shown in my answer. Also, if you are looking for a free programmer you'd better pay one, [SO] is about helping people that show some effort.

Comment: @Vigenesh. This should work. Which version of awk you are using?

Comment: Did it solve your problem, @Vignesh ? Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark this or anubhava's answer accepted if your problem is already solved. You can do it clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 2):

Following awk should meet both of your requirements:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $2 {nz=1;print}; END{if (!nz) print "all zeroes, send email"}' file
```

- You just need to replace `print "all zeroes, send email"` with your mail sending command.

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$sed '/\S+\s+[0]+\b/d' file
Table_name Value
student    50
animals    20
$sed -r '/\S+\s+([1-9]|[0]+[1-9])/!d' file
student    50
animals    20
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simply with awk,

```
awk -F " " '{if($2 > 0) print $0}' your_file
```

Comment: It is good, but note that you are using a few options that are already set on default: `-F " "`, `print $0`.